# Change the parent background-image/color for each child on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want my parent div to change background-color/image depending on witch child div is hovered. I need 4 different childs div to affect the parent.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Div1" class="elmt">div1</div>
    <div id="Div2" class="elmt">div2</div>
    <div id="Div3" class="elmt">div3</div>
    <div id="Div4" class="elmt">div4</div>
</div>
```

little fiddle test (not working -_-') http://jsfiddle.net/TyL6G/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution with dynamic tag. If you find a better way to do it you are welcome to share. :)

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
$('#container>div[image]').hover( function(){
  $(this).parent().css("background-image",$(this).attr("image"));
   },
   function(){
      $(this).parent().css('background-image','url(link.jpg)');
   });
});
```

check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TyL6G/15/

Answer (score 2):

This is a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) issue. The `.newColor` class background color does not overwrite the `#container` background color because an `id` is more specific than a class.

Use a more specific selector to apply the background:

```
#container.newColor {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x397R/)